Can I use both Greenhouse-Geisser AND Huynh-Feldt?
Basically I'm doing a repeated measures ANOVA with the following interactions:
Stimulation,
Emotion,
Time-Stimulation,
Time-Emotion,
Stimulation-Emotion,
and Time-Stimulation-Emotion
Mauchly's Test of Sphericity was violated and the Greenhouse-Geisser ε is > .75 for some, and < .75 for others. My sample size is fairly small (19) so I'm leaning more towards Huynh-Feldt. I'm wondering, can I use a combination of both corrections or do I just pick the one that fits better?
